# openapi_core validate_request really poor error description

Tags: python, rest, openapi

So i use:

```
from openapi_core import validate_request
```

To validate request data versus schema:

```
validate_request(request_data, self.spec)
```

Here's the snipped for request body:

```
 getRequest:
  type: object
  properties:
    type_of:
      type: string
    name:
      type: string
```

My request:
r = requests.post(url='host/something/v012/get', data={'type_of': 'user', 'name': 'test'})
The error message raised is:

```
E                   Request body validation error
```

Not sure what's wrong based on the error desc
Do you guys know a better way to see more exact error descriotion (what's wrong with the request data vs yaml?)

Openapi_core version 0.18.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **cause** attribute to get the exception that led to the validation error. For example:

```
from openapi_core import validate_request
from openapi_core.validation.request.exceptions import RequestValidationError

try:
  validate_request(request_data, self.spec)
except RequestValidationError as e:
  print(e.__cause__)
  raise e
```